# How to use partition on a join to get a count

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-partitioning

I'm confused on how to get a `count` without using `group by` on a `join`

I know I can get the desired results using `group by`, but the table joins are long and lots of selected headers with case statement so I was hoping to avoid that

I'm sure I've seen this done before using `partition over` but can't find a good example using it on a join. Maybe it's not possible!?

I've tried

```
select
    p.FirstName,
    p.Surname,
    count(pr.RelativePersonId) over (partition by pr.RelativePersonId) as [RelativesOnRecord]
from People p
left join PersonRelatives pr
    on p.PersonId = pr.PersonId
```

For my tables:

People

```
PersonId | FirstName | Surname
   1          Jim       Bo
   2         Harry      Bo
   3         Strong     Bo
```

PersonRelatives

```
Id | PersonId | RelativePersonId
 1      1              2
 2      1              3
```

Where I'm trying to get

```
PersonId | FirstName | Surname | RelativesOnRecord
    1         Jim         Bo          2
```

I also tried joining with a `SELECT TOP 1` but that just gives me the one result so one count. Is this even possible without `group by`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are partitioning by the wrong column - you want to have the number of relatives for each person from `People`, right ? Use

```
count(pr.RelativePersonId) over (partition by pr.PersonId) as [RelativesOnRecord]
```

Comment: Ah yes! that gives me the right count but also leaves me with two identical rows - I guess I could use `DISTINCT` to filter them - I feel like I might be breaking some SQL law but it works for me for now!

Comment: Watch out for identically named Persons with different ids which may have the same number of relatives on record (depending on your use case, it might not matter).

Comment: Thanks, good point, in reality there are quite a few more identifiers for a person but I think actually I'll just include their ID to be safe! I will accept this answer when it lets me. So simple I can't believe I didn't even try it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, you *want* aggregation:

```
select p.PersonId, p.FirstName, p.Surname, count(*) as [RelativesOnRecord]
from People p join
     PersonRelatives pr
     on p.PersonId = pr.PersonId
group by p.PersonId, p.FirstName, p.Surname;
```

You could use `apply` or a correlated subquery, but window functions do not seem appropriate here.

Comment: Why do window functions seem inappropriate here?